# CSS to make a div span full height?

Tags: css

I'd like to know how one goes about figuring out the CSS that will make the first `div` in the HTML below (the one with `class="left-col"`) span the full vertical height of the page. (NB: this "full vertical span" property of the `div` should hold even if scrolling is required to see the bottom of the page, and also, it should not be affected by any resizing of the window, possibly with reflowing of the rest of the layout.)

I'm more interested in the reasoning/rationale/thought process leading to the desired CSS than in the CSS code itself.  IOW, I'm not looking for a one-time incantation, but rather I'm looking for an example of how to reason through such problems.<sup>1</sup>

(BTW, I've found some SO threads that also ask about making a `div` span the height of a page, but the solutions given in those threads do not apply to the general case described above (e.g. they fail if the full height of the page is greater than the height of the viewport, so vertical scrolling is required to view it all).  More importantly, none of the solutions I've found explain why they should work, so they don't provide the understanding I'm primarily after.)

---

(Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YYrfT/) for the code given below.)

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  outline:0;
}
.right-col{
  min-width:160px;
  max-width:320px;
  margin-left:auto;
  font-family:consolas,monaco,courier,monospace;
  font-size:22px;
  line-height:43px;
}
.left-col{
  width:80px;
  background-color:orange;
}
```

```
<body>
  <div class="left-col"></div>
  <div class="right-col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur id nisi placerat, commodo elit sed, lacinia elit. Curabitur at malesuada nunc. Curabitur fermentum, neque at molestie lobortis, ligula mauris placerat felis, in hendrerit libero orci tempor sapien. Donec vel ultricies enim. Fusce tempus ante vitae purus laoreet laoreet. Maecenas urna felis, feugiat at lorem vitae, iaculis elementum nisi. Mauris venenatis lacinia nunc, sit amet bibendum tortor faucibus ac. Quisque lobortis condimentum diam, eget luctus odio iaculis in.  Praesent malesuada velit at scelerisque porta. Nam dui arcu, mollis imperdiet semper vel, malesuada in nulla. Integer volutpat varius tortor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer iaculis odio et semper venenatis. Mauris quis convallis odio, nec ornare mauris. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse pharetra mollis tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ornare ac tortor a volutpat. Sed ac bibendum tortor. Morbi vitae augue in dui ultrices convallis vel eu massa.  In congue gravida leo, et vehicula lacus posuere fermentum. Suspendisse molestie ipsum sit amet accumsan luctus. Pellentesque nec blandit ipsum. Aliquam magna risus, iaculis eget sapien quis, tristique sagittis diam. Etiam consectetur dapibus augue quis egestas. Phasellus pellentesque scelerisque ligula eget consequat. Maecenas bibendum nibh vel aliquet rutrum. Nullam faucibus diam diam, vitae hendrerit erat rhoncus non. In semper tortor eu leo hendrerit venenatis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</div>
</body>
```

<sub><sup>1</sup>In particular, I am not interested in solutions that achieve a "similar look" by entirely different means (e.g. through the use of a background image or of a run-time setting of style properties with JavaScript).  I'm aware of such alternative solutions, and do not need help with them.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Since you are basically trying to create a two-column layout, I would personally try to rely on `display: table-cell`. If you are not familiar with this display type, it's pretty much the CSS equivalent of a `<td>` tag, but you don't really need to wrap it in a complete `display: table` layout if you don't want to. The benefit with this display type is that it will both force itself to stay on the same line as its siblings, as well as span the entire height of its parent.

Here's a basic example (without regard of margins e.t.c) of how it looks: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVv74/1/)